c# Unable to download file from WPF webBrowser control
I am using WPF WebBrowser control and that will load our own URL which will have a hyperlink to download the screenshot or any files when we click on that link I get a popup saying "Help protect your security your web browser blocked this site from downloading files" and it won't download the file, the same thing is working in Windows form WebBrowser.
Any input will appreciated.
Thanks.

Maybe  you should check the system's security settings, especially the IE settings. WebBrowser is a kind of obsolete class. It uses the Internet Explorer browser engine, which is quite antiquated. I recommend using the WebView2 control. It's based on Edge and Edge uses the modern Chromium browser engine. You probably have to install the NuGet package: Get started with WebView2 in WPF apps. Maybe this will alos solve your problem.
